# <a href> link that adds query parameter to currently existing query parameters

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, query-string

How to create a `<a href="?param2=17">` link such that:

- if the current URL in the browser is `example.com/index.html`, clicking on it leads to `example.com/index.html?param2=17`
- if the current URL in the browser is `example.com/index.html?foo=bar`, clicking on it leads to `example.com/index.html?foo=bar&param2=17` **and not** `example.com/index.html?param2=17`
- if the current URL in the browser is `example.com/index.html?foo=bar&param2=10`, clicking on it leads to `example.com/index.html?foo=bar&param2=17` **and not** `example.com/index.html?foo=bar&param2=10&param2=17`

TL;DR: a link that adds query parameter to the current URL **instead of totally removing the current query parameters**.

If not possible with HTML, what's the simplest Javascript way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `onclick` attribute to you `a` tag and implement the callback getting the event target and merging it with the `window.location`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @MetallimaX's answer, here is a working solution:

```js
function update(a, b) {
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (b != '')
        searchParams.set(a, b);
    else
        searchParams.delete(a);
    window.location.search = searchParams.toString();
}
```

```html
<a onclick="update('foo', 'bar');">Click on my link</a>
```